# Multiple Inner Joins on Same Table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do multiple joins on the same table and after I add so many MYSQL loses connection. I know that I am doing too much with this code and choking the database. Here is the code I am using. How do I simplify this and make it more efficient?

````
SELECT 
  y.`value` AS `Year`,
  m.`value` AS `Make`,
  mo.`value` AS `Model`,
  t.`value` AS `Title`,
  se.`value` AS `Seller Email`,
  v.`value` AS `VIN`,
  p.`value` AS `Posted`,
  e.`value` AS `Expired`,
  d.`value` AS `Expire Date`
FROM
  (SELECT `record`, `value` FROM thrn1_facileforms_subrecords WHERE `name`='vehicleYear') AS y
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT `record`, `value` FROM thrn1_facileforms_subrecords WHERE `name`='sellerEmail') AS se
  USING (`record`)
  INNER JOIN
(SELECT `record`, `value` FROM thrn1_facileforms_subrecords WHERE `name`='vehicleVin') AS v
  USING (`record`)
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT `record`, `value` FROM thrn1_facileforms_subrecords WHERE `name`='yearMakeModel') AS t
  USING (`record`)
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT `record`, `value` FROM thrn1_facileforms_subrecords WHERE `name`='vehicleadExpired') AS e
  USING (`record`)
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT `record`, `value` FROM thrn1_facileforms_subrecords WHERE `name`='vehicleModel') AS mo
  USING (`record`)
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT `record`, `value` FROM thrn1_facileforms_subrecords WHERE `name`='vehicleMake') AS m
  USING (`record`)
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT `record`, `value` FROM thrn1_facileforms_subrecords WHERE `name`='expireDate') AS d
  USING (`record`)
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT `record`, `value` FROM thrn1_facileforms_subrecords WHERE `name`='datePosted') AS p
  USING (`record`)```
````

Comment: I suggest to improve your query. If you can share what you want to achieve with this query, we might help.

Comment: Why can't the query be like `SELECT * FROM thrn1_facileforms_subrecords WHERE name='xxxxx'`? It's all coming from the same table anyway. Unless there are some necessity to do so, please tell us what is it? thanks

Comment: I am trying totake data from a flat table and create a normalized table.

Answer (score 0):

The connection is lost most likely because the client is closing the connection after waiting too long for a result (a client timeout). You can increase this value and will eventually get an answer.

The real problem here is the use of the "Entity Value Attribute" anti-pattern. You are using different rows to store different types of data, thus having to run this mega-join to get what you want. Instead, you should try to have all the data of a given record in a single row with as many columns as needed.

The only reason I'd consider the EVA pattern is when an application lets the user define 'custom fields'. And yes, too many such fields will generate extremely inefficient queries.

Comment: > The real problem here is the use of the "Entity Value Attribute" anti-pattern. You are using different rows to store different types of data, thus having to run this mega-join to get what you want. Instead, you should try to have all the data of a given record in a single row with as many columns as needed.

Yes, the table is a flat style with columns stored in rows instead of columns. Unfortunately it is built by Breezing Forms for Joomla. What I want to do is take that data and create a new table that has columns as it should be.

Comment: I suggest you try: 1) increasing the client timeout, 2) converting the table in parts (say, run the conversions in batches of 100-1000 records, 3) If the number of records of some of the types is small you can try writing code to pull the records and join in your application (create a hash-map and join manually).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. I wish I knew what all of that meant. So the way I am doing it is correct. You have to join every time you get another row? Is that correct? It just chokes the server, and to be honest, there are less than 100 rows.

Comment: Very strange. But if it's only 100 rows, write some code to load everything into memory and perform the join in the code (with no SQL).